# NetBeans 7.4 Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans

I'm getting an error when trying to deploy an project to AppEngine using NetBeans.
I installed the plugin for NetBeans and I can run the application localy using appengine-java-sdk-1.9.0

When I try to deploy the program I get the following message:

```
Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\Adi\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8079434123068806992.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Compiling jsp files.

Error Details:
Mar 10, 2014 11:50:04 PM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: \guestbook.jsp


java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.
Unable to update app: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.
Please see the logs [C:\Users\Adi\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg5934545421821565182.log] for further information.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you need to download JDK: you've only downloaded JRE so far.

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson is right. Link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: Hi, I already have JDK 7_51 installed. I read some answer in here about this issue but only for eclipse but not for NetBeans.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, this is my first answer in stackoverflow. Please consider, if I break some rules do not hesitate to tell me whats wrong or should be changed in future.

**I run into same problem like Amir Rossert.** 
I've installed the Bundle "Netbeans 8 + JDK 8" (jdk-8u25-nb-8_0_1-windows-x64.exe from Oracle website). Additionally I have installed JDK 7 which I needed for different cases.

In Netbeans both JDKs were displayed under Tools/Java Platform Manager
JAVA SE

- JDK 1.7
- JDK 1.8 (Default)

So far so good.
When I changed JAVA_HOME to JDK 1.7 (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72) I still get 
java -version 1.8 !?

**Why: Because Netbeans**

1. has installed/copied 3 following files

   - *java.exe*
   - *javaw.exe*
   - *javaws.exe*
     into *C:\Windows\System32*
2. linked them from directory *C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath* and
3. after all set system variable Path (not PATH) = *C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;*

So whenever I wanted to use 1.7 it didn't work, instead 1.8 was used.
And when I wanted to deploy to Google Appengine the Exception occur: *Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.*

**I solved it this way:**

1. I deleted all three files mentioned above (*java.exe, javaw.exe, javaws.exe*)
2. I deleted the directory *C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath*
3. I deleted the value *C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;* in system variable *Path*:

**After that I tried out to deploy on Google Appengine again, this time successfully.**

Answer (score 2):

I just found an answer to this issue on:
appcfg can't find javac?[1](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/google-appengine-java/RyFybJWUhU4/78UE_2FL5sJ)

> Unfortunately it's more complicated than that. The very first entry in your path points to C:\Windows\system32. There is undoubtedly a java.exe living in that folder who's home is actually the JRE in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6. (You can test this yourself by running a small Java program):
>
> System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
>
> AppCfg uses the system property, java.home, of the currently running JVM to look for javac. Since you're running the java.exe which belongs to a JRE, it goes looking for the compiler there. Unfortunately, there's no real universally consistent or great way to automagically find the most appropriate java compiler. For our SDK, the rule is that you need to be running the JVM from your SDK, not from a JRE. As I mentioned in my previous post, this is most easily accomplished by just setting your Java SDK at the front of your path. For example,
>
> set PATH=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;%PATH%
>
> We've certainly been mulling over ways to make this simpler and more bulletproof.

After editing the PATH I was able to deploy my app to the appengine with NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with NetBeans but I'll give you the steps to fix this on Eclipse hopefully you will find the equivalent ones:-

- Right click on your project and choose properties
- Go to java build path
- Then under libraries tap, scroll to your selected JRE System Library
- Edit the JRE to point to the directory where you installed you JDK.

If the above is already done, and you only see such errors when deploying, do the following

- Edit the configuration settings file of your IDE and give it the following argument then restart it, in the Eclipse it is at the main directory where the Eclipse at and called `eclipse.ini`.

  -vm
  C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javaw.exe

Comment: Hi,
I checked the project properties and it has the JDK defined and not JDE.
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=k35643&s=8#.Ux7oVfl_s8U

In addition, the NetBeans use 'netbeans.conf' file and it have the JDK folder listed correctly
http://tinypic.com/r/2jfyh36/8

Do you have any more advices?

Thanks

Comment: Hi,
I just tried to use the appcfg command from CMD to deploy the app and I get the same error message
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE."